# after installing a new distribution I don't have access to my previous Home partion files

Tags: files, filesystems, system-installation, home, kubuntu

after installing a new distribution I don't have access to my previous /home partition files but about 121 GB of volume is full also If I try live mode I can see them.

I tried:`ls -la` in /home directory
But there is nothing from the previous only the files that Kubunto created.

-Distribution name: Kubuntu

-File system: Btrfs

-Previous Distribution: Debian

Additionally, I didn't change the previous File system it was Btrfs and it is.

the volume size is 887 GB and the system says that 14 percent of files are full plus I can run files that I don't have access in normal mode through live mode

The live mode `pwd` Returns
/media/kubuntu/ffd1acb6-7765-483d-a767-3546d328e3d7/amirhossein

something that I think is useful to say is my user name for Kubuntu is amirhossein so it has created another file with the name of amirhossein

the picture in live mode amirhossein is my Debian files that here shows
[image]

what should I do? Is there any way to have access to my files?

lsblk -f Result
[image]

Comment: What precisely do you see in live mode? You run `ls -la` on which directory? Is /home on a separate partition or logical volume? If so, to see it you need to mount it. Which volume is full? How much space of that volume was used before? In general you should not be surprised that more disk space is used after adding an operating system.

Comment: @berndbausch I took a picture in live mode and wrote the directory name. I run ls -la in /home Yes home is in a separated partition that has about 930 GB and my filesystem has 45 I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run:

```
lsblk -f
```

And then paste the output here...

When you have finished the first command login as root on normal mode and run the following commands, **This will erase data on the new /home**

```
rm -fr /home
mkdir /home
```

Add `UUID=ffd1acb6-7765-483d-a767-3546d328e3d7 /home btrfs rw,realtime,nofail 0 0'` to `/etc/fstab` but remove any other mentions of /home as it is the old home

Comment: OP says "If I try live mode I can see them". This means that /home has not been overwritten. However, `lsblk -f` is definitely a useful step.

Comment: in Live mode or normal should I run ```lsblk -f```

Comment: @Amirhossien Salighedar On the normal mode, but dont run the second command until i review the output of the first command...

Comment: ```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                                    
sda                                        
├─sda1 btrfs        ffd1acb6-7765-483d-a767-3546d328e3d7  764.7G    14% /home
├─sda2 swap         ddb78757-e868-4910-9ef9-38cdff091ad6                [SWAP]
├─sda3 jfs              fd94dbc0-3011-4571-a738-e16fbeb4b50f  749.1M    21% /boot
├─sda4                                                                  
└─sda5 jfs              1cd0c34d-740a-4b31-81f9-25d477522b86   32.2G    17% /
sr0
```

Comment: Do you have important things on the new home?

Comment: yes I have important things

Comment: Then run on normal mode
```
sudo sh -c 'mkdir /mnt/home && mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/ffd1acb6-7765-483d-a767-3546d328e3d7 /mnt/home'
``` And from gui move everything out of /mnt/home out to /home...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126690/discussion-between-julian-and-amirhossien-salighedar).